# Matlab - content filtering using strings

Tags: matlab

```
k = strcmp(word{w},com_word{y});
if(k) new_word = strrep(word,word{w},'');
```

Say i wanna do something like this , comparing two strings word by word for example:

> str1 : ' my world is awesome '
>
> str2 : ' my world was awesome '

Now i want to compare the words in `str1` with those in `str2` and remove the common words in both. Finally, only ' is ' remains in `str1`.

Comment: It would really help us if you posted what you've tried and detail what, exactly, isn't working. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 3):

Tools that you can use here - `regexp`, `strtrim`, `setdiff`.

**Code**

```
str1 = ' my world is awesome '
str2 = ' my world was awesome '

split1 = regexp(strtrim(str1),'\s','Split')
split2 = regexp(strtrim(str2),'\s','Split')

str1_exclusive = setdiff(split1,split2)
str2_exclusive = setdiff(split2,split1)
```

**Output**

```
str1_exclusive = 
    'is'
str2_exclusive = 
    'was'
```

Comment: yeah , thanks ! but the str1_exclusive and str2_exclusive are in the cells' format, what if we want them to be just strings ? as that what we read from a text file ?

Comment: @PriyamSoneji Use `char()`.

Comment: sorry to be asking such questions , i'm doing it for the first time, but it gives it in a columnar format only , while displaying , can't it be in a row format ? like our initial strings are ?

Comment: @PriyamSoneji That's okay! We learn things as we try them out!

Comment: How do we get it to come as an actual string ? As our initial strings were ?

Comment: @PriyamSoneji That's what I said, you need to use `char`. So, as an example, you can use - `char(str1_exclusive)` and `char(str2_exclusive)`.

Comment: again, no reputation , so can't chat with you over this, but now , this filtered string we get , i need to check the number of occurences of each word in it in another text file's content ? How to go about that ?

Comment: @PriyamSoneji Okay, that could be posted as another question.

Comment: yep, did. How to go about that ? 
Thanks a lot for helping , i really need to see this through !